# Access localdb data in a view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, localdb

I'm starting an ASP.NET core mvc project now and I'm having trouble showing information in a specific view.

I have 2 models that contain their specificity and I need to have access to both in a view declared in the HomeController. Here is one of the models:

```
public class Tipo_Logradouro
    {
        public int Id  { get; set; }
        public string Abreviatura { get; set; }
        public string Nome_Tipo { get; set; }
    }
```

My intention is to present "Abreviatura" and "Nome_Tipo" through a cshtml table with all the data already registered. But when I try it gives an instance error and I can't present it. The controller methods for this model were made via scaffold.

I don't know if it is possible to do this or if it is something very simple, but I am starting and I want to resolve this situation.

PS: The cshtml that I am trying to present the information, is outside the scope of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have 2 models that contain their specificity and I need to have
> access to both in a view declared in the HomeController.

Although the view can only accept one type of model, you can have several methods to display multiple different model data in the same view.

**First way:**

You can **combine the two models that need to display data into a new model**, and then receive the new model in the view to display the data of different models.

```
public class Tipo_Logradouro
    {
        public int Id  { get; set; }
        public string Abreviatura { get; set; }
        public string Nome_Tipo { get; set; }
    }
```

Another model:

```
   public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; } 
    }
```

Combined new model:

```
public class CombineModel
    {
        public List<Tipo_Logradouro> Tipo_Logradouros { get; set; }
        public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }
```

controller:

```
public IActionResult ShowData()
        { 
            CombineModel combineModel = new CombineModel()
            {
                Persons = _context.Person.ToList(),
                Tipo_Logradouros = _context.Tipo_Logradouro.ToList()
            };
            return View(combineModel);
        }
```

View:

```
@model CombineModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ShowData";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>ShowData</h1>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<Person>)Model.Persons)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Id</td>
            <td>@item.name</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<br />
<br />
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Abreviatura</td>
        <td>Nome_Tipo</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<Tipo_Logradouro>)Model.Tipo_Logradouros)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Id</td>
            <td>@item.Abreviatura</td>
            <td>@item.Nome_Tipo</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**Second way:**

You can use **ViewData** to pass another model to view :

Controller:

```
 public IActionResult ShowData()
        {
            List<Tipo_Logradouro> data = _context.Tipo_Logradouro.ToList();
            ViewData["data"] = data;
            List<Person> persons= _context.Person.ToList();
            return View(persons);
        }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Person>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ShowData";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>ShowData</h1>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Id</td>
            <td>@item.name</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<br /><br />
<table  class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Abreviatura</td>
        <td>Nome_Tipo</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<Tipo_Logradouro>)ViewData["data"])
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Id</td>
            <td>@item.Abreviatura</td>
            <td>@item.Nome_Tipo</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Here is the test result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through a list of Tipo_Logradouro objects, and in the loop read the value of the Abreviatura and Nome_Tipo properties.

When you debug do you get your data from the database? Or are you usin in-memory database?

Comment: I was using a localdb, but I was able to resolve the situation, thanks